# how to preselect value in dropdownlist in jsp struts

Tags: drop-down-menu, struts, selection

i am working web application on struts 1.3 in netbeans i have two dropdownlist say A and B now i have no probl1em in populating these dropdowns on jsp load ,now user select one value from say dropdown A and value user selected say it is 1 and for another dropdown say B user selected value which is 2 and now user will save these values in database now  my requirement is that when we go in edit mode for that when page loads dropdownlist A should have value  1 as preselected and  dropdownlist B should have value  2 as preselected. and these values are coming from database 
my jsp page

1 dropdown

```
        <tr>  
       <td> <html:select name="RoomForm" property="location"onchange="getFloorDropdown(this.value);" >
                       <html:option value="0">Select Location</html:option>
                       <html:optionsCollection name="RoomForm" 
                       property="list" value="id" label="name"  />
                   </html:select>
               <td>
  </tr>
```

RoomForm:-name of my form bean in requst scope
list:-Arraylist collection
id:-it is property in Arraylist which is list having getter and setter in bean
name:-it is property in Arraylist which is list  having getter and setter in bean

2 dropdown

```
<select name="floor" >
<option value="0">Select Floor</option>
</select>
```

how should i do how select a preselected values in both downdroplist when this form opens in edit mode
any hint will be a great help for me

Answer (score 0):

Zohaib,

In the action that is responsible for retrieving the information from the database, populating the relevant ActionForm and finally loading the Edit view, the ".location" property of that ActionForm must be populated with the value stored in the database. In the JSP, you are going to associate that ActionForm instance as the form backing object. Struts will automatically do the rest, i.e. ensuring that the correct option shows as selected.

HTH.

Ashwin